# how to detect when a sprite passes an object in AndEngine

Tags: android, position, entity, andengine, sprite

I am trying to implement a function in my game that will add to your score once you pass an object in the level. I've tried:

```
if (player.getY() < levelObject.getY())
{
     addToScore(1);
}
```

This is inside my levelLoader method, but it is not adding to the score when the player passes the object. I assume this is because the code has to be initialized in some way to check the Y position of both entities, but am not sure how to do this or what would be the best way. Any help or ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure- are you aware that in android the Y axis starts from the upper left corner and increases as you go down?

Comment: Do you know that you can check if sprites contact with eachother? There is sprite.collidesWith(Entity) method that checks sprite collisions